# What does "<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">" do?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I can't believe what is happening in my website. When I add this line:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
```

Everything works fine. And when I don't, CSS "messes" up, everything becomes different and layout becomes "ugly".

How can this line solve all the problems?!

Comment: Do you have a valid doctype in the first line of your HTML?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the line *above* that one that's making the difference? What browser are you testing with?

Comment: @Dominic Barnes: my first lines are: `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>`

Comment: @hey: So let me get this straight: If your first two lines are `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!DOCTYPE html>` - then everything works fine. But if your first two lines are `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>`, then everything is broken? Is that the case? If so, it's umm.. not good.

Comment: What I think was actually going on was this: The <!DOCTYPE html> specified HTML 5 and the document isn't HTML 5. Adding the HTML tag above it didn't get it processed as XHTML -- it got it processed as HTML 4 (Quirks Mode). The xmlns line was ignored, as was the HTML 5 doctype and the extra <html> element.

Comment: @Oriol: I'm reopening this as I think an answer specific to HTML/XHTML would be useful (even if just to say "it allows XHTML 1.0/1.1 markup to validate, and does nothing in HTML5 and you can leave it out of an HTML5 document").

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You're mixing up [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Markup_Language) with [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML).

Usually a `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration is used to distinguish between versions of HTMLish languages (in this case, HTML or XHTML).

Different markup languages will behave differently. My favorite example is `height:100%`. Look at the following in a browser:

### XHTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    table { height:100%;background:yellow; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>How tall is this?</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

... and compare it to the following: (note the conspicuous lack of a `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration)

### HTML (quirks mode)

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    table { height:100%;background:yellow; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>How tall is this?</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

You'll notice that the height of the table is drastically different, and the only difference between the 2 documents is the type of markup!

### That's nice... now, what does `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` do?

That doesn't answer your question though. Technically, the `xmlns` attribute is used by the root element of an XHTML document: (according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML#Root_element))

> The root element of an XHTML document must be `html`, and must contain an `xmlns` attribute to associate it with the XHTML namespace.

You see, it's important to understand that XHTML isn't HTML but [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) - a very different creature. (ok, a kind of different creature) The `xmlns` attribute is just one of those things the document needs to be valid XML. Why? Because someone working on the standard said so ;) (you can read more about [XML namespaces on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Namespace) but I'm omitting that info 'cause it's not actually relevant to your question!)

### But then why is `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` fixing the CSS?

If structuring your document like so... (as you suggest in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838343/what-does-html-xmlns-http-www-w3-org-1999-xhtml-do/#comment-6704060))

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
[...]
```

... is fixing your document, it leads me to believe that you don't know that much about CSS and HTML (no offense!) and that the truth is that *without* `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` it's behaving normally and *with* `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` it's not - and you just *think* it is, because you're used to writing invalid HTML and thus working in [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html).

The above example I provided is an example of that same problem; most people think `height:100%` should result in the height of the `<table>` being the whole window, and that the `DOCTYPE` is actually breaking their CSS... but that's not really the case; rather, they just don't understand that they need to add a `html, body { height:100%; }` CSS rule to achieve their desired effect.

Comment: `"and thus working in quirks mode"` - I also think this is the case. As I said in my comment, `"If so, it's umm.. not good."`.

Comment: that's a brave attempt at an explanation, but a bit muddled. When discussing the height:100% matter, it would be better to leave XHTML out, since it's only the DOCTYPE (mostly just its presence or absence) that's relevant, not whether it's HTML or XHTML syntax. Then explain the namespace as being a property of XHTML separately.

Comment: your HTML is missing doctype and you are implying a table-based layout

Comment: @teresko - True, but that's kind of the point ;) @Alohci - This is also true, but I didn't want to stray too far from `xmlns`, so I used XHTML so as to include it therein.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I was writing invalid HTML for some of the things. Thank you.

Comment: HTML should have a doctype.

Comment: @Marcin - And I contradict that assertion how?

Comment: Your html example lacks one.

Comment: You mean the one which follows the "(note the conspicuous lack of a <!DOCTYPE> declaration)"? The example which is part of my explanation as to why the OP's markup is rendering as quirks mode HTML instead of XHTML? The one meant for the OP to try in a browser and go "ohhhh my markup is rendering in quirks mode because I'm not using a DOCTYPE!" Is that the HTML example you're referring to?

Answer (score 33):

Its an XML namespace. It is required when you use XHTML 1.0 or 1.1 doctypes or application/xhtml+xml mimetypes.

You should be using HTML5 doctype, then you don't need it for text/html.  Better start from template like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>domcument title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
            <!-- your html content -->
            <script src="/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

When you have put your Doctype straight - do and validate you [html](http://validator.w3.org/) and your [css](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) .
 That usually will sove you layout issues.

Comment: I like this answer more. Short and simple.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like your site has CSS or JS that depends on running in quirks mode.  Which is why you need garbage above your doctype to render "correctly".  I suggest removing said garbage and then fixing your CSS+JS to actually work in standards mode; you'll save yourself a lot of pain in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

```
The namespace name http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
is intended for use in various specifications such as:

Recommendations:

    XHTML™ 1.0: The Extensible HyperText Markup Language
    XHTML Modularization
    XHTML 1.1
    XHTML Basic
    XHTML Print
    XHTML+RDFa
```

Check here [for more detail](http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/)