# An odd pairing with Doctype?

Tags: html, xhtml, frontend

I use this common modern doctype to signify HTML 5 and so does the new site I'm working on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I don't do anything to the HTML tag ( it's just `<html>` so I found it strange when I started working on a new site and found they used:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
```

What exactly is this line doing.  The type of HTML being used has already been specified.

Can the `xmlns` and `lang` attributes be removed or are they performing some function?

**Research**

[xmlns - xml namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104438/what-does-the-xmlns-attribute-do)

Comment: What's the DOCTYPE on this new site? Typically specifying xhtml in the XML namespace would suggest that XHTML was being used, not HTML5... I suppose you could specify an XML namespace for an HTML5 document, and use [XHTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558502/is-html5-valid-xml) but that would be fairly rare, in my experience.

Comment: Why not try [Google](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=html%20xmlns) and find the [first link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_html_xmlns.asp)?

Comment: @Zen-LeeChai Well, is the document actually XML? If it is, and something's going to parse it, that would be a good reason to use the namespace. If it's not actually XML (e.g. it omits end tags) then it's pretty pointless.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558502/is-html5-valid-xml

Answer (score 2):

The `xmlns` attribute specifies the xml namespace of the document. According to [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/conformance.html), it is required for `XHTML`.

> The start tag of the root element of the document MUST explicitly contain an xmlns declaration for the XHTML namespace [XMLNAMES]. The namespace URI for XHTML is defined to be http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml.

See [this excellent SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1181936) for more information.

`html5` is not entirely XML-based, there it does not need a namespace-declaration.

You can read some information about the `lang` attribute here: [W3 Org on Language Tags](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/). Basically it specifies the target reader language.

Comment: @Doorknob Point taken, switched source to w3.org.