# Doctype html - do you need an html tag after it?

Tags: html, doctype

If you set you page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Do you need an html tag like

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

after it?

Cheers guys.

Comment: nope, `<!DOCTYPE html>` is all thats needed.

Comment: you don't technically need it, but I'd raise hell at anyone who left it out just because.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In any HTML version other than XHTML versions, the `<html>` tag is not needed and does not have any effect as such. However, the tag is useful for specifying the main language of the content of the entire document, e.g. `<html lang="en">`.

In XHTML, the tag is always required and must have the `xmlns` attribute as in the example. (It may additionally have other attributes.) The tag is required, because the `html` element is present in any XHTML document, and XHTML never allows start tag omission. The attribute is required because a specific XHTML rule says so.

This has nothing to do with the doctype issue. Using `<!DOCTYPE html>` is nowadays common and often seen as “the HTML5 doctype”. The above still applies, since HTML5 has two alternative syntaxes, the HTML syntax and the XHTML syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag is just a declaration to let your browser know that its reading an html document. Since HTML5, all you need is the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag.

From w3schools:

> The  declaration must be the very first thing in your HTML
>   document, before the  tag.
>
> The  declaration is not an HTML tag; it is an instruction to
>   the web browser about what version of HTML the page is written in.
>
> In HTML 4.01, the  declaration refers to a DTD, because HTML
>   4.01 was based on SGML. The DTD specifies the rules for the markup language, so that the browsers render the content correctly.
>
> HTML5 is not based on SGML, and therefore does not require a reference
>   to a DTD.

More info from w3schools here:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela are you serious? this 100% answers the question, and w3schools reports the information correctly. Just because some developers are not fans of w3schools vs w3c, does not mean that information I referenced is wrong by default; *just 'cause*. Here is an additional resource verifying my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5838366/2259303 . You can not like my answer but it doesn't mean that I deserve a down vote.

Comment: The question was, as even the question title says, about the need for an `<html>` tag. You only say something about doctype. Besides, w3schools is wrong as usual; e.g., in reality, no browser has ever read a DTD.