# Explanation of html:5, html:xml, html5-boilerplate

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Can anyone explain the difference between the different html options show in the vscode screenshot below? When to use each one. Thanks!

[image: Vscode]

Comment: These days, just use `html:5`.

Comment: Btw, on VS code, By typing "!", it gives the boilerplate code

Answer (score 2):

For me, `html` and `html:xml` only generate the opening and closing html tags.

`html` generates `<html></html>`

`html:xml` generates `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></html>`

But `html:5` generates a basic boilerplate for any html5 compatible html file. It contains some basic stuff like, doctype, head, body, title tags etc.

Answer (score 1):

`html`: create only `<html></html>` tag

`html:5` : create a basic html 5 template as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

`html:xml` : Usually a `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration is used to distinguish between versions of HTMLish languages (in this case, HTML or XHTML). [More detail about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5838444/6052427)